# MySql selecting default value if there are no results?

Tags: mysql

i'm having 2 tables: members and comments.
I select all members, and then join comments.
But in comments I'm selecting some SUM of points, and if user never commented, I can't get that user in listing?!

So how to select default value for SUM to be 0 if user never commented, or some other solution:

```
SELECT c.comment_id AS item_id, m.member_id AS member_id, m.avatar, 
            SUM(c.vote_value) AS vote_value, SUM(c.best) AS best, 
            SUM(c.vote_value) + SUM(c.best)*10 AS total
            FROM members m
            LEFT JOIN comments c ON m.member_id = c.author_id
            GROUP BY c.author_id
            ORDER BY m.member_id DESC
            LIMIT 0, 20
```

---

**EDIT:**

I will try to explain...
So there are 2 tables, members and comments. I need listing of all users with ranking.
Comments hold all votes and best answers.

So, I need listing of all users, and they score.

**Members table:**

```
member_id - username - avatar
```

**Comments table**

```
comment_id - author_id - vote_value - best (0 OR 1)
```

Also tried to select from COMMENTS and join MEMBERS, but same thing again :(

Comment: Can you provide some example data with an expected output? I don't use MySQL, so maybe they have some shortcut syntax, but you're GROUPing on only one column but have several non-aggregated columns in your SELECT

Comment: @Tom H.: MySQL actually allows this syntax: [GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I knew at least one of the major RDBMSs allowed that, but couldn't remember which. Because it allows "illogical" groupings though, it could result in "missing" data because "When using this feature, all rows in each group should have the same values for the columns that are ommitted from the GROUP BY part. The server is free to return any value from the group, so the results are indeterminate unless all values are the same."  c.comment_id may not always be the same for a given c.author_id

Comment: I edited my question with table structures, maybe it will help to better understood. Thanks

Comment: Try breaking down your query and building it back up to see what part breaks it. Start with just "SELECT m.member_id, SUM(c.vote_value) FROM ..." to make sure that works, then add in the other SUMs and columns one at a time to find the problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are including the comment_id in your SELECT list if you just want users and their rankings. Do you want only their ranking on that particular comment? I'll give a solution for now that assumes you just want a full member list with rankings:

```
SELECT
    M.member_id,
    M.user_id,
    M.avatar,
    COALESCE(SUM(C.vote_value), 0) AS vote_value_sum,
    COALESCE(SUM(C.best), 0) AS best_sum,
    COALESCE(SUM(C.vote_value), 0) + SUM(C.best) * 10 AS total_value
FROM
    Members M
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments C ON
    C.author_id = M.member_id
GROUP BY
    M.member_id
ORDER BY
    total_value DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

(this assumes that vote_value and best are NOT NULL columns or that MySQL will disregard those when calculating SUM values - I believe that it does, but I haven't tested that)

Answer (score 23):

MySQL has an IFNULL operator which allows you to return a value other than null if the result is null.

```
SELECT c.comment_id AS item_id, m.member_id AS member_id, m.avatar, 
            SUM(IFNULL(c.vote_value, 0)) AS vote_value, SUM(IFNULL(c.best, 0)) AS best, 
            SUM(IFNULL(c.vote_value, 0)) + SUM(IFNULL(c.best, 0))*10 AS total
            FROM members m
            LEFT JOIN comments c ON m.member_id = c.author_id
            GROUP BY c.author_id
            ORDER BY m.member_id DESC
            LIMIT 0, 20
```

As others mentioned, COALESCE does something similar (and also works in MySQL).

Comment: That's probably a little better than `COALESCE` for the circumstance of wanting a default value.

Comment: Also no all users in listing :\

Comment: Then it's very likely that @nathan is correct. Try grouping on m.member_id instead of c.author_id to see if that helps.

Comment: Still nothing :( I edited my question with tables and structure, maybe it will help, Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I use `COALESCE` for this sort of thing.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

I would rewrite your second and third lines as:

```
COALESCE(SUM(c.vote_value), 0) AS vote_value, COALESCE(SUM(c.best),0) AS best,
COALESCE(SUM(c.vote_value), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(c.best),0) * 10 AS total
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the SUM is the problem.  I think it may be your

```
GROUP BY c.author_id
```

where you are grouping by the right side of a left outer join.  I'm not sure what that does when the right side doesn't exist, but I'm guessing that's not what you really want.  You most likely should be grouping by something in members, not comments.

Having said that, yes, you should also use COALESCE or IFNULL to turn null values to 0.

Comment: Tried with grouping m.member_id but still same, not all users in listing. I edited my question with table structures, maybe it will help to better understood. Thanks

Comment: Try breaking down your query and building it back up to see what part breaks it.  Start with just "SELECT m.member_id, SUM(c.vote_value) FROM ..." to make sure that works, then add in the other SUMs and columns one at a time to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the if statement to convert NULL to 0

```
SELECT c.comment_id AS item_id, ...
    IF(SUM(c.vote_value) is null, 0, SUM(c.vote_value)) as vote_value
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN comments c ON ...
```

Comment: COALESCE does that same thing, but is simpler.  SUM(COALESCE(c.vote_value, 0))

Comment: That's a clunky mechanism for doing it.  `IF (x is NULL, y, x)` isn't very tidy.

Comment: @nathan: didn't know that before but just had use for it. Thanks (btw. I had to use COALESCE(SUM(col), 0) because the other way round still returned null.

Answer (score -1):

You could have a look to the CASE Statement, too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

In your case the result would be similar to...

```
SELECT c.comment_id AS item_id, m.member_id AS member_id, m.avatar, 
        (CASE SUM(c.vote_value) WHEN NULL THEN 0  
        ELSE SUM(c.vote_value) END) AS vote_value, SUM(c.best) AS best, 
        (CASE SUM(c.vote_value) + SUM(c.najbolji)*10 WHEN null THEN 0
        ELSE SUM(c.vote_value) + SUM(c.najbolji)*10 END) AS total
        FROM members m
        LEFT JOIN comments c ON m.member_id = c.author_id
        GROUP BY c.author_id
        ORDER BY m.member_id DESC
        LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: That's extra-clunky, unfortunately.