# Consider average rating as Zero in case that Roll No is not in the Rating List in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, average

Consider the following schema:

```
Student (RollNo int Not Null, Name varchar(20) Not Null, YearOfAdmission int Not Null,
PRIMARY KEY(RollNo))
```

```
Friend(OwnRoll int Not Null, FriendRoll int Not Null,
PRIMARY KEY(OwnRoll, FriendRoll),
FOREIGN KEY fk_std1(OwnRoll) REFERENCES Student(RollNo),
FOREIGN KEY fk_std2(FriendRoll) REFERENCES Student(RollNo))
```

```
Movie(MID int Not Null, Title varchar(30) Not Null, YearOfRelease int Not Null, DirectorName
varchar(20) Null,
PRIMARY KEY(MID)) [Assume all director names are unique. However, same director can direct
many movies]
```

```
Rating(RollNo int Not Null, MID int Not Null, RatingDate date Not Null, Rating int Not Null,
PRIMARY KEY(RollNo, MID, RatingDate),
FOREIGN KEY fk_std4(RollNo) REFERENCES Student(RollNo),
FOREIGN KEY fk_mov2(MID) REFERENCES Movie(MID));
```

Now Ques is as follow:

**List the students whose average rating over all movies (including multiple instances of rating
the movies on different dates) is less than the average rating of those movies by his/her friends
(including multiple instances of rating the movies on different dates). (Output format: RollNo1,
AverageRating1, RollNo2, AverageRating2)**

One of the possible answer is -

```
Select x.OwnRoll as RollNo1, l1.average as AverageRating1,
x.FriendRoll as RollNo2, l2.average as AverageRating2
from 
(
Select * from Friend 
union 
(
Select f.FriendRoll, f.OwnRoll from Friend as f
)
order by OwnRoll
) as x,

(
Select r.Rollno, avg(r.Rating) as average
from Rating as r 
group by r.Rollno
) as l1,

(
Select r.Rollno, avg(r.Rating) as average
from Rating as r 
group by r.Rollno
) as l2
where l1.Rollno = x.OwnRoll and l2.Rollno = x.FriendRoll
and l1.average > l2.average ;
```

But this version doesn't consider the friends who have never rated a movie, thus their average rating is 0

Thanks in advance for any update to the question and its answers.

Comment: **The motivation behind adding this question was to get a better and simple solution than the one I just posted below**

Answer (score 0):

Do this litte update to capture rating average as 0 in case Roll No is not there.

```
Select distinct r.Rollno, avg(r.Rating) as average
from Rating as r 
group by r.Rollno
union
(
Select RollNo, 0 as average
from Student 
where Rollno not in (Select RollNo from Rating)
)
```

You can even follow Coalesce more about which mentioned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp)

Similar Question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922637/mysql-selecting-default-value-if-there-are-no-results/2922748)

**Final Answer is**

```
Select x.OwnRoll as RollNo1, l1.average as AverageRating1,
x.FriendRoll as RollNo2, l2.average as AverageRating2
from 
(
Select * from Friend 
union (Select f.FriendRoll, f.OwnRoll from Friend as f)
order by OwnRoll
) as x,

(
Select distinct r.Rollno, avg(r.Rating) as average
from Rating as r 
group by r.Rollno
union
(
Select RollNo, 0 as average
from Student 
where Rollno not in 
(Select RollNo from Rating))
) as l1,

(
Select distinct r.Rollno, avg(r.Rating) as average
from Rating as r 
group by r.Rollno
union
(
Select RollNo, 0 as average
from Student 
where Rollno not in 
(Select RollNo from Rating))
) as l2

where l1.Rollno = x.OwnRoll and l2.Rollno = x.FriendRoll
and l1.average > l2.average
```

Try understanding it step by step !! Else you will get lost :)